# Brand new mac pro tower has really slow wifi? iPhone and macbook pro 2016 get 100Mbps, while mac pro gets 1/3 of that

Tags: wifi, mac-pro

I've run out of ideas.

I'm right next to my router/access point. I have an iphone, a macbook pro 2016, and a mac pro tower that I've had for a few months. All of them running fast.com show 100Mbps, but the mac pro only ever gets to about 25-30Mbps. It was definitely not this slow in the past, and so I'm not sure if a recent update broke something, but I keep dropping calls and stuff as of late on the mac pro. Any ideas for how to troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: First test - [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/What_can_I_do_about_Bufferbloat/) - though tbh, on a desktop Mac I'd just use Ethernet.

Comment: Please detail exactly what kind of Mac Pro tower you have. Which year/model do you have.

Comment: Added an image @jksoegaard

Comment: Hold down the option-key while clicking the WiFi icon in the top menu bar. Compare the information across your Mac Pro and MacBook Pro (add screenshot here if you don't know what to look for).